# Best international alternative to Java's getClass().getResource()

Tags: java

I have a lot of resource files bundled with my Java app. These files have filenames containing international characters like ü or æ. I would like to load these files using getClass().getResource(), but apparently this is not supported since for these particular file names, the getResource method always returns null.

That made me experiment with using URL encoding of the international characters, but this is not supported either as stated by https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4968789.

So, my question is: What is the recommended way of loading a resource which has a name containing international characters? For example, I need to load the UTF-8 contents of a file named Sjælland.txt

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there is a `best` (it is probably a candidate for `worst` because it is quite a hack) but this seems like a capable mechanism. It sidesteps the need to use `getResource` by reading the jar directly.

```
public class NavelGazing {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    // Do a little navel gazing.
    java.net.URL codeBase = NavelGazing.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    // Must be a jar.
    if (codeBase.getPath().endsWith(".jar")) {
      // Open it.
      java.util.jar.JarInputStream jin = new java.util.jar.JarInputStream(codeBase.openStream());
      // Walk the entries.
      ZipEntry entry;
      while ((entry = jin.getNextEntry()) != null ) {
        System.out.println("Entry: "+entry.getName());
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I added a file called `Sjælland.txt` and this did successfully get the entry.

Comment: That is interesting. I could see why that would work. However, I think it would take some more work for proper performance, since you are opening a zipped jar everytime you read a file. Before going down that road, I will see if anyone else has other alternatives to share.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand you correctly, but if I try

```
URL url = Test.class.getResource("/Sjælland.txt");
Object o = url.getContent();
```

then `o` is a `sun.net.www.content.text.PlainTextInputStream`.

I'm using [JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) 1.6 on a Windows machine. I've got (default?) System.property sun.jnu.encoding set to Cp1252. So it all seems to work fine. The bug you've posted seems to be JDK 1.4. It might be what you're using.

Comment: No, I am on Java version: 1.7.0_10-ea, Java vendor: Oracle Corporation on a Mac. This used to work fine with Java 1.6.x from Apple. I will take a look at the encoding – maybe that's it...

Comment: I tried using a sun.jnu.encoding setting of UTF-8, since this page says that's what the mac uses:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/04-JavaUIToolkits/JavaUIToolkits.html

I also tried using the Normalizer to decompose the filename as is custom in the Mac file system with this line:

resourceUri = Normalizer.normalize(resourceUri, Normalizer.Form.NFD);

Still, it does not work.

Comment: If I look up the folder and list its files using Java.io I find a filename of
Sj��lland.txt
The codepoint values are [83, 106, 65533, 65533, 108, 108, 97, 110, 100, 46, 116, 120, 116]
So the 'æ' is represented as two characters somehow.

Comment: @RandahlFinkIsaksen I don't know if you still read this, but my attention was drawn to this question when Peter edited my answer. Have you tried setting the file.encoding system property (as a startup parameter) to UTF-8 ?